# How to compare two JSON by the elements and not the values using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I've seen related questions but this is on the assumption that you want to make sure the values are also the same despite the order in the JSON.

Mine is on the assumption that the two JSONs will also be the same order but just have different values, how will you know that they are the same? What I care about is that both JSONs have the same elements.

For example, these two JSONs match

```
{orderid:1,price:1.0000,qty:2,status:NEW}

{orderid:2,price:1.1000,qty:1,status:FULFILLED}
```

But these do not

```
{orderid:3,price:2.000,qty:4,status:NEW}

{orderid:4,price:3.000,qty:5,status:NEW,returned:NO}
```

Obviously when I compare simply with == or with items() it doesn't work because it checks if even the value is the same, and this is why I've been struggling.

Is there a way I can just run an XOR and if XOR returns anything it becomes false? I'm wondering if I can make the JSON a set but make sure the values are removed so they don't cause problems with the comparison.

Comment: @jpp That will only work if the JSON objects are flat.

Comment: If your two JSON objects are flat, like in your example, the answers in the linked question are all you need. If your JSON is nested, then things are a little trickier.

Comment: @jpp thankfully they are flat for the most part. Would the json be automatically considered a dictionary or do I have to change the type?

Comment: If you use the standard library [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) or `json.loads` functions to load the JSON data shown in your question it will get loaded into a plain Python `dict`.

Comment: oh my god thank you thank you so much it WORKS. My code finally works the way I want it to.